# Export Paper Model addon not exporting textures

Tags: texturing, uv, export, add-on, texture-baking

Does the Export Paper Model addon ([found here](https://github.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender/blob/blender28/io_export_paper_model.py)) have the capability to map the textures of the model onto the faces of the paper model? The documentation suggests that it does, but I have no idea how to do that. Thanks!!